# startService() and stopService() not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The problem I'm currently experiencing is that I am unable to start and stop the service of another class. I was able to run the application but I couldn't get the results I wanted, as the program didn't show any errors. I thought it was something wrong with my buttons at first, so i tried using System.out.println to see if i get any feedback, in which i did. Then, i decided to try it on my other class (location.java), the System.out.Println I used did not work, which probably means its not even working.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
private EditText input;
private Button start, stop;
private Intent intent;
public static int minute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iniUI();
}

private void iniUI() {
    input=findViewById(R.id.input);
    start=findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop=findViewById(R.id.stop);
    start.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(false);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    intent=new Intent(this, Location.class);
    permission();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId()==R.id.start) {
        minute=Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
        startTracking();
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.stop)
        stopTracking();
}

private void permission(){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        start.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode==0){
        if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            permission();
        }
    }
}

private void startTracking(){
    startService(intent);
    buttonAlt();
}

private void stopTracking() {
    stopService(intent);
    buttonAlt();
}

private void buttonAlt(){
    start.setEnabled(!start.isEnabled());
    stop.setEnabled(!start.isEnabled());
}}
```

Location.java

```
public class Location extends Service{ private Thread thread;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private double longitude, latitude;
private String dateTime, encodeData;

public Location() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    thread = new Thread(runThread);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    thread.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private Runnable runThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Shutting down");
                long sMinutes = MainActivity.minute * 60 * 1000;
                Thread.sleep(sMinutes);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Running");
            sendLocation();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}


private void sendLocation() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    android.location.Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    longitude=location.getLongitude();
    latitude=location.getLatitude();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    dateTime=sdf.format(date);
    postData();
}

private void  encodeData() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    encodeData= URLEncoder.encode("datetime", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(dateTime, "UTF-8") +
            "&" + URLEncoder.encode("latitude", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Double.toString(latitude), "UTF-8") +
            "&" + URLEncoder.encode("longitude", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Double.toString(longitude), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Lat:"+latitude);
    System.out.println("Long:"+longitude);
}

private void postData(){
    try {
        encodeData();
        URL url=new URL("A PHP SCRIPT TO OBTAIN MY LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE");
        URLConnection urlConnection=url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        outputStreamWriter.write(encodeData);
        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Location"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

To sum it all up, both classes showed no errors, but only the MainActivity.java was working. Is there anything i could change about it to get it to work? I think it has something to do with my startService() and stopService().

Comment: If you try to debug and add a breakpoint at the onCreate method callback in Location class, or a print or Log, do you get to see it?

Comment: @sgtpotatoe nothing showed up when i tried adding System.out.printLn in the oncreate method of the location class.

Comment: is it registered in the manifest too?

Comment: @sgtpotatoe Yep, i even remembered to add permissions

Comment: I mean the service so like in Manifest:

PERMISSIONS

 <activity
                android:name="MainActivity" />
<service
                android:name=".Location"
                android:exported="false" />

Comment: @sgtpotatoe just realized that i used <activity> instead of <service>, no wonder it didn't worked, thanks!

Comment: Ah great! I'll put it as an answer so you can accept it and close the question! glad to help! @menace2anus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like in your Manifest file you have registered your service Location.java as an activity, it should work once you change that to service

```
<service android:name=".Location" />
```

instead of

```
<activity android:name=".Location"></activity>
```